# How do I get a background image to resize without affecting text wrapping?

Tags: swiftui

Adding `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)` to the image that's in the ZStack above the content in a VStack makes the text wrapping fail and the text goes to a single line that spills over the edges of the screen.

How do I get the text wrapping while also keeping the fill aspect ratio on the image?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(
                "backgroundimage"
            )
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill) // deleting this line makes the text wrap
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(
                .all
            )
            VStack {
                Text(
                    "Some really long text. Some really long text. Some really long text."
                ) // this is the text that is not wrapping
            }
            
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image has stretched the frame outside the screen, so you can't see the whole text. If the text is extremely long, you can only see the whole text horizontally and vertically if you give it a proper frame. You can use GeometryReader to get the screen size and assign it to the frame.

```
struct TextWrapView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Image("backgroundimage")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    //add a frame of screen size
                    .frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width, maxHeight:geometry.size.height)
                VStack {
                    Text("Some really long text. Some really long text. Some really long text.")
                }
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

However, if you only care about wrapping text horizontally as you described, you can ignore the frame height and use the frame like this:

.frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width)

or this:

.frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width, maxHeight: .infinity)

Answer (score 1):

Its because the `ZStack`s width depends on the element inside, which is `Image`, and it's larger than screenWidth. You can wrap the entire content inside `GeometryReader` to make the largest width is the parent view.

```swift
GeometryReader { geo in
    ZStack {
        Image(
            "backgroundimage"
        )
        .resizable()
        .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width)
        
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `ZStack`, you can use a `background` modifier on the stack that holds the text (or on the text itself, if you wanted). Note that you'll want to make sure that stack takes the full width/height using the `frame` modifier.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(
                "Some really long text. Some really long text. Some really long text."
            )
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(
            Image("backgroundimage")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(
                    .all
                )
        )
    }
}
```